# Parse Crash Reporting blocks application

Tags: android, parse-platform, crash-reports

After call

```
    throw new RuntimeException("Test Exception!");
```

Parse blocks ui thread and nothing ever happens.

Only Android OS soon offers to close the application because it is not responding.

Comment: please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

It was because of using both

gms.analytics.Tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true)

and

ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

There was some conflict in Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()